# Improve start/destination matching for HERE FLEET Route API

Tags: rest, routes, here-api

we are using the HERE FLEET route calculation API to calculate a route between two points.
Our URL looks like this:

```
https://cre.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?app_id=XXX&app_code=XXX&storage=readonly&overlays=OVERLAYf0134c87a6404690aab2994d73c03824&waypoint0=geo!48.331953,10.904123;50&waypoint1=geo!48.380098,10.902750;50&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&language=de-de&routeattributes=sh
```

As you can see, we are using a radius for our waypoints (in this example: 50 meters).
This requests fails with following error message:

```
Cannot match 48.331953/10.904123 onto a road link with 50.0m search radius
```

The next logical step would be, to start the same request again, but for example with a radius of 100 meters, instead of 50 meters.

I think, this is kind of ugly, because I have to start multiple requests (at the beginnig with a small radius and later with larger radius) to calculate a single route.

Is it possible, to tell the API, that it should handle the right radius by itself (it could start with a really smart radius (5meters) and increase it further and further to find the right road link)?

Thanks for your help!
Simon

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove the radius and leave only the coordinate. I tried and it worked.